# Audio Playback android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create audio playback from a previously recorded audio recording saved in external storage on SD card. The Recording part works fine, but I am unable to create the MediaPlayer using setDataSourceFD and am getting the error java.io.IOException: setDataSourceFD failed: status=0x800000000. I appreciate any feedback or help.

Thanks.

Comment: since you re new here: post more details what you are trying to do. or post some logcat output... could be you didn't set the permission read from storage in your xml, could be you re setting your audiofile wrong...IOException is usually, that you re trying to do something with an object, that doesn't exist...

Comment: thanks longiling. I will put more detail in...not sure how to copy my logcat off eclipse. Sorry about the lack of detail (I am very new here). i set up the permission read and write in the xml...and have confirmed the that file exists in the SD card using the debugger. Logcat basically says Unable to create Media Player java.io.exception. I understand that io exception means that the file doesnt exist...but the debugger tells me that my path name is correct.

Comment: Try installing a file manager app and seeing if you click on the sd card file in that if it will play.  If not, you know the problem is with the file.  But if it does play, you know the problem is with your program.

Comment: @Chris Stratton...thanks for the advise...i checked the sd card file and my recording plays so the file is being found, so the error lies with my program. im using the create method for MediaPlayer then player.start()... my log cat says start called in state 1...so i think im calling start() before MediaPlayer is ready...but i'm not sure how to fix this.

Comment: Ok, so it's an issue in the program.  I'd suggest you either look for a working MediaPlayer example, or post the code of your attempt.

Comment: @Chris Stratton I got the issue working by preparing player and setDataSource in different try/catch brackets. Previously, I had both statments in 1 try followed by catches for both. Apparently it didnt work...but problem solved! Thanks for everyone's help.